# Facebook debugger redirecting due to rel alternate meta tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, redirect

I have a website that runs in several languages. We use meta tags like so to define for crawlers the alternate urls:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/us/eng-us-url-here" hreflang="en-US" rel="alternate" />
<link href="http://www.example.com/gb/eng-gb-url-here" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate" />
<link href="http://www.example.com/fr/french-url-here" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate" />
```

... etc

When I use the Facebook debugger to test the french URL for example I am shown an error:

```
Object at URL 'http://www.example.com/fr/french-url-here' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

Even though all the tags are there. Clicking on 'see exactly what our scraper sees for your URL' shows that it is in fact doing a weird redirect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/fr/french-url-here?fb_locale=en_GB/">redirected</a>.</body>
</html>
```

Why is that redirect happening? Its surely something controlled at the server side, but the doctype is different so maybe this is something else. We're using a fairly standard Rails app.

Also if it is being redirected, why does Facebook not follow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the redirected URL, it has appended `?fb_locale=en_GB`.

It would be nice if Facebook followed conventions but according to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/11/605/ if you want this to work with Open Graph you need to do two things:

1. Include `og:locale:alternate` meta tags in the head:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

2. Render different OG tags depending on what language is specified in the URL parameters:

```html
<!-- for my.site/index?fb_locale=en_AU -->
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_AU" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_AU"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="G'day" />
```

Detecting Facebook parameters and having them scrape each page multiple times was overkill for my needs. Instead I switch locale for the whole site and have different OG partials depending on the current locale:

`apps/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= I18n.locale %>">
  <head>
    <title><%= page_title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= render "layouts/open_graph" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
...
</html>
```

`apps/views/layouts/_open_graph.en.html.erb`:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.url %>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="New World 5k" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A free, weekly walk/run open to all! 5km and 2Mi options available." />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= image_url "/images/og_logo_en.png" %>" />
```

As you can see above, this also lets me have different OG images per language:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook **scraper** doesn`t follow your links. If your main page is using redirect this is the data facebook will get. I would strongly advice against using redirects like that couse it is bad for SEO. If the **scraper** result is nowhere to be found in your site code the issue could be the server. I had a problem like that. My server used to set cookie then reload the page witch of course confuses the **scraper**. You should use php or similar server side language to detect your user location and provide the data accordingly. Hope that helps.